# Midi in browser on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, web-browsing, midi

I recently moved on Mountain Lion. It seems that the OS does not allow midi playback in browser anymore. I can't find more informations but this threads: [1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4169578?start=0&tstart=0) ; [2](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/147628-mountain-lion-and-midi/)

Can you help me to find a solution to get back my good old midi files in web pages?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome still allows this, Safari doesn't. It is a per-browser configuration. To my knowledge, Safari does not currently have an option to re-enable this.